# Fourier expansions at the cusps of $\Gamma_0(N)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

My question may be basic but I can't find any answer. Let $N$ be a positive integer. I need to find the constant term (of the Fourier series) at each cusps of a modular form
$$f(\tau)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a(n)q^n} \quad , \quad (q=e^{2i\pi \tau}, \tau \in \mathcal{H})$$
(where $f$ belongs to the space $\mathcal{M}_2(\Gamma_0(N))$) just by knowing its Fourier series at $i \infty$.

I know that the constant term is $0$ at $i \infty$ and since I can assume that $f$ is an eigenvalue of the Fricke involution $w_N$, I can deduce that it must also be $0$ at the cusp $0$. What else can I say ?

When $N=p$ is prime, I can conclude. But since I am working on a general result, I can't do those assumptions on $f$ : I can't explicit $f$ by a basis of $\mathcal{M}_2(\Gamma_0(N))$, neither.

Many thanks for your help !

Comment: I think the key phrase you may be looking for is "Atkin-Lehner involution".

Comment: If $N$ is large, then the space of such modular forms is large, and the information you've given is not sufficient to determine the constant terms at other cusps.  More specifically, nothing you've said has removed the obvious ambiguity given by scalar multiplication.

Comment: @S.Carnahan: Certainly the Fourier coefficients at a given cusp determine the Fourier coefficients at any other cusp. I think the OP wants a simple transition formula, but I doubt such a thing exists.

Comment: @PeterHumphries : I heard that the Atkin-Lehner involution method was only working in the case where $f$ is a cusp form and a new form. Can you please explain me the general method ? (Thanks !)

Comment: @GHfromMO : Yes that is almost what I want : but I am only interested in the constant term.

Comment: If $f$ is a cusp form, then it vanishes at all cusps. Else, $f$ is a linear combinaison of Eisenstein series : thus, can we find a certain basis for the Eisenstein-space for which one knows the constant term at each cusps of each element of the basis ?

Comment: @Stabilo yes, this has been worked out by Henri Cohen, see arXiv:1809.10908